# How to enable dark mode in serverfault

Tags: linux

I have been using stack overflow for a few months now, and I really enjoy the dark mode feature. I recently tried to find the same feature on serverfault, but I couldn't seem to find it. Does anyone know if there is a way to enable dark mode on serverfault?

Could someone please tell me how to activate dark mode here?